# Seaborn hue causes Pandas warning

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

```
pd.__version__ : '2.2.0'
pd.__version__ : '3.8.2'
pd.__version__ : '0.13.1'
```

When i'm using hue in Matplotlib, it will throw warning like below.

warning:
FutureWarning: When grouping with a length-1 list-like, you will need to pass a length-1 tuple to get_group in a future version of pandas. Pass `(name,)` instead of `name` to silence this warning. data_subset = grouped_data.get_group(pd_key)

Suppose no warning at all

Comment: This is due to a sudden change in pandas version 2.2.  You can upgrade seaborn to 0.13.2 to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.